# In Symfony2 how do I apply new Indexes using ORM?

Tags: symfony, indexing, doctrine

I have just discovered the ORM\Index annotation and have gone through my entities to add in all the indexes I should have on my tables.

But I now don't know how to apply these changes to my database.

I tried doctrine:migrations:diff but it didn't pick up the changes.

Is there any other commands that I can use (without rebuilding the database) or will I have to apply all the indexes manually in mysql?

edit: I was being stupid. The indexes I added to test were on ManyToOne fields, which already get indexes. I've added an index to one of my data fields and migrate picked it up.

Comment: no, `doctrine:migrations:diff` should be able to pick them, please post your entity with indexes

Comment: Have you cleared your cache and reset you mapping cache (I usually just reboot the server)?

Answer (score 1):

> doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

will give you a list of all the mysql changes that will occur.

> doctrine:schema:update --force

will apply those updates for you (do not do this on production)